# Excell Color cell with a specific number based on cell value in another page

Tags: excel, fill

I have a diagram with unit numbers on one page and a list with unit numbers and names on another page. I would like to color the diagram cell if there is a name by the unit number on the other page.. My list page has the unit numbers, size, name. If the name column is filled, then the diagram with the corresponding number would be filled with yellow. If I take the name off the list, then the cell would go back to being no fill.

For example, unit 347 on the diagram would be colored if unit 347 on the list page has a name in the correct column cell. But no fill if it doesn't.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiQKE.png)

Thanks!!

I tried to do a conditional formatting but don't know how to check that the numbers match in one cell and fill based on value of another cell in that row.

Comment: Try conditional formatting with: "use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Comment: I tried conditional, but im not sure of the formula that would match cell values then look at another cell to determine color fill or not.

Comment: =A3=B3 will check if the contents are equal. other operators can be used. < > etc

Comment: I might not be explaining this right.. So if on sheet 1 A4 has a value of 347, it then looks on sheet 2 finds the row that has a Value of 347 (A348) then sees if C348 has any TXT. If it does then A4 on sheet 1 would get filled yellow, if not no fill. this would apply to A4:BC49 on sheet 1 and reference A1:C390 on sheet 2.